# purge ALL dependencies

Tags: linux, dependencies, package, aptitude

I've a problem that seems quite simple, but I can't get it done. I have a package with many dependencies and I want to remove ALL of them, regardless wheather other packages also depend on them ( they get removed too ). How can I get a list of all dependencies of a package that I can easily send to xargs aptitude purge ? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

`aptitude search -F '%p' '~R^gnome$'`

You can actually purge them by changing `search` into `purge`, without `xargs`.

In case of dependency problems, `aptitude` will ask what to do, proposing some resolutions. You can then browse through them (ncurses UI is useful in this case, propositions are better explained).

Be careful not to uninstall important base packages. They are sometimes mentioned in package dependencies too.